# Obtain entity using coroutines api

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

What is the best way to use `coroutines` with LiveData for selecting some data from database using `Room`.

This is My Dao class with suspended selection

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from user_table WHERE id =:id")
    suspend fun getUser(id: Long): User
}
```

Inside of View Model class  I load user with `viewModelScope`.

**Does it correct way to obtain user entity ?**

```
fun load(userId: Long, block: (User?) -> Unit) = viewModelScope.launch {
    block(dao.getUser(userId))
}
```

According  [developer android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)  mentioned

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(data)
}
```

This chunk of code does not work

Comment: Please clarify how it doesn't work. Is the function you posted your version of `database.loadUser()`? Yours is not a suspend function and doesn't return a user (it returns a coroutine Job).

Comment: room could not compile project when I set return type  LiveData<User> for single item.

Comment: Not enough info to debug it. I don't know which function you're talking about and how you're using it. The code in your question doesn't match up by function name or return type.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check again @Tenfour04

Comment: I still can't see how you are calling this `load` function.

Comment: OK. The load function inside of repository.

Comment: So now I know where it is, but still not how you are calling it. Also, how does the repository have access to `viewModelScope`? You're going to have to show a lot more code for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: suspend fun load(id: Long): User {
        return dao. getUser(id)
    }

Comment: What do you mean by, does not work? is anyone observing `user`?

Comment: the problem is load user should be not suspended otherwise project build filed. But as mention in doc of google "loadUser is a suspend function."

Comment: What is the reason for the project not compiling? The `liveData{}` supports calling suspend functions from within it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Room must return LiveData.

Use instead:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from user_table WHERE id =:id")
    fun getUser(id: Long): LiveData<User>
}
```

Comment: If it returns `LiveData` then it should not be `suspend`

Comment: you are write. When I remove suspend keyword code is compiled success

Comment: Room supports suspend functions. Also, `LiveData` is not a required return type.

Comment: You can choose to use LiveData or Coroutines. But its for differents proposes, livedata will observe changes on Room, and the Coroutines will get you data from DB without block the UI Thread.

Comment: I understand the differences. What I am trying to point out is that the OP wants to use suspend functions which do not require the return type to be LiveData. I believe there is something else going on and changing the return type to LiveData is not probably the solution.