# Retrieve single record with Room to populate an Edit dialog (activity or fragment)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a database table which stores some records. I have been able to correctly populate a RecyclerView in a Fragment, following tutorials like [this one](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0) and similar ones found via search engine.

What I want to do next is to tie an "Edit record {id}" fragment that is tied to the RecyclerView. In other words, if I click on an item in the Recycler view, another fragment(or activity) should open, load the data for record[id] **from the database** and then allow me to save and update the record if needed.

The point where I am stuck is retrieving the single record from the database, because I systematically end up with either (1) calling the query inside the main thread, which Room prevents me from doing, or (2) getting some random null pointer.

I have seen solutions even [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859988/obtain-single-user-using-coroutines-with-livedata), but I can't make sense on how to integrate them in my case.

What I can't make sense of is how to make the async call (whether with threads/coroutines), store the result in a variable, and use it to populate the fields in the Edit fragment.

Internet search have been very disappointing, for all I find are (duplicate) tutorials that are either incomplete, irrelevant or obsolete.

Good pointers are welcome. I would prefer *not* to use third party libraries to do this, unless someone can explain to me the advantages in doing so.

Sorry for the long post: I haven't added code because there would be too many pieces to show and you would probably know anyway. I will answer any questions however to help out.

Also, I am new to Kotlin/Android, and I am trying to tame this beast :-)

Comment: You need to do the same thing as for a list, except you can return a single item.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That's where I don't know how. For the list I have a LiveData/Observer construct, and the async method doesn't return anything itself, just does something. For the single item, I don't know how to actually get the value passed outside the coroutine/thread/whatever. Might be very basic, but can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Comment: For the Single item, you have `LiveData<T?>`.

Comment: No, I don't. Do I need to have an observer even for a single record? I assume that's where a LiveData path would take me...

Comment: Of course. Aren't you waiting for it to be queried on a background thread, and for it to notify you if that single item was deleted from a background thread?

Comment: Right. I am not expecting background deletion, but you are right. I must be missing a piece (or two, or three...) of the whole puzzle.

Comment: Might not be *expecting* one, but that doesn't mean you can never get one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to say anything specific without any code, but the correct way to do it would be

1. Retrieve all records from `Room`
2. Load them in your `recycler` `view`, so `recycler` `adapter` will have a `list` of all your `records`
3. setup on `click listener` in your `recycler adapter` to open the next `activity` or `fragment`
4. pass the `primary key` (as in room) of clicked item to the next `activity` or `fragment`
5. In your next `activity` retrieve a record from `room` using the `primary key`
6. bind the retrieved record to `UI`

If your `recycler view` and `adapter` are correctly setup then you should have following in your adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
   // dataList contains all your records as retrieved from room
   // and loaded in your recycler view
   setListeners(dataList[position], holder)
   holder.bind(dataList[position])
}

private fun setListeners(selectedRecord: YourRecordTypeInRoom, viewHolder: YourViewHolder){
     viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(viewHolder.itemView.context, NextActivity::class.java)
            // pass primary key to next activity
            intent.putExtra("primaryKey", selectedRecord.primaryKey)
            viewHolder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
     }
}
```

***Now to retrieve your single `record` you should have something as follows in your `dao`***

```
@Query("Select * FROM your_table where primaryKey = :primaryKey")
fun findByPrimaryKey(primaryKey: PrimaryKeyType): YourRecordType
```

Edit:
You can also modify the `return` type of above `function` to be a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) `object`, which will allow you to observe it in your activity in an async manner. with live data your code would look some thing as follows.

In `Dao`

```
 @Query("Select * FROM your_table where primaryKey = :primaryKey")
 fun findByPrimaryKey(primaryKey: PrimaryKeyType): LiveData<YourRecordType>
```

In your `view model`

```
 fun getRecordByPrimaryKey(primaryKey: PrimaryKeyType) = yourDao.findByPrimaryKey(primaryKey)
```

and in your `activity` or `fragment`

```
viewModel.getRecordByPrimaryKey(primaryKey).observe(this, Observer{
   // Bind your record on UI
})
```

Comment: yes, so far we are aligned. The problem I have is that `findByPrimaryKey` needs to be asynchronous somehow. When I do that, I don't know how to actually get the record out of the async method. Might be the silliest question, but I haven't figured this out. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @sal You can use live data to achieve that, let me make an edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you: right now I am stuck at the "bind the record to the UI". While I debug the reason why I am getting all "null" values too :-) This is helpful, believe me.

Comment: Ok, essentially I am *finally* getting something working: following your lead, I added the `viewModel.getRecordByPrimaryKey` to my fragment `onCreateView`. The `primaryKey` parameter was retrieved during `onCreate` from the `Bundle` and stored in a `private var`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Return `fun someFunction():LiveData<Model>` in Room class, (you should be able to call it from Main thread). After getting value once, you can stop observing, since you want only single value

2) You can use Kotlin Coroutines, this way you return `suspend fun someFunction():Model`. You can only call this function from another Coroutine, so it will be something like:

```
class ViewModel{
   fun normalFunction(){
      viewModelScope.launch{
          val result = room.someFunction()
          // tell View that you have result (View observes result using LiveData)
      }
   }
}
```